# What is the correct way to reload a tableView from inside a nib?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which shows a custom cell.
Inside the cell is a button.

Once the button is clicked, a network call is made and the tableview should reload.

I tried this, but I get `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` at `vc.reloadData()`.

```
  @IBAction func acceptRequestPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        DatabaseManager.shared.AnswerFriendRequest(emailFriend: friendNameLabel.text!, answer: true) { success in
            if success {
                
                let vc = FriendRequestViewController()
                vc.reloadData()
                
            }else {
                print ("error at answer")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The phrase `friendNameLabel.text!` means "Please crash me". You can hardly be surprised when it does exactly that. However, that's not actually the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let vc = FriendRequestViewController()
```

After that, `vc` is the *wrong view controller* — it is just some view controller living off emptily in thoughtspace, whereas the view controller *you* want is the already existing view controller that's already in the view controller hierarchy (the "interface").

Comment: Yes, and you should do the call off the current thread.

Comment: See my essay http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers:

1. You can have a closure upon the data call completion in your class that has the table view.
   Eg:

   // Custom Table Cell Class
   class CustomCellClass: UITableViewCell {

   ```
    let button = UIButton()
    // All other UI set up

    // Create a closure that your tableView class can use to set the logic for reloading the tableView
    public let buttonCompletion: () -> ()

    @IBAction func acceptRequestPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        DatabaseManager.shared.AnswerFriendRequest(emailFriend: friendNameLabel.text!, answer: true) { [weak self] success in
            if success {
                // Whatever logic is provided in cellForRow will be executed here. That is, tableView.reloadData() 
                self?.buttonCompletion() 

            }else {
                print ("error at answer")
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }

// Class that has tableView:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    private let tableView = UITableView()
    .
    .
    // All other set up, delegate, data source
    
    func cellForRow(..) {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueTableViewCell(for: "Cell") as! CustomCellClass
    
        cell.buttonCompletion = {[weak self] in
            tableView.reloadData()
       }
}
```